# How to dynamically set pylint path using .pylintrc?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I am trying to set up linting for a Python project using pylint in Visual Studio Code. I am managing dependencies using conda and have pylint installed through there, but VSC defaults to putting the global reference to pylint as the path (`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pylint`) instead of the conda installation for this project (`/opt/miniconda3/envs/tf/bin/pylint`).

I was able to solve linting issues by manually changing the VSC setting to the conda installation; I am wondering if there is a way to include this in the `.pylintrc` so that my teammates cloning this repo can get linting without messing with their settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found a workaround but I am not sure if it will work with VSC. I always use the *pylint* from the base env and rewrite the *sys.path* at pylint init to the currently active conda environment. This prevents *E0401* errors without installing *pylint* in all the conda environments.

I use the following config in `~/.pylintrc`:

```
[MASTER]
init-hook = "import os, sys;\
             sys.path = [s.replace('/opt/anaconda3', os.getenv('CONDA_PREFIX'))\
                         for s in sys.path]"
```

`/opt/anaconda3` is my base anaconda env path and should be replaced by yours (`/opt/miniconda3` apparently). I did not find a way to get this value automatically.

The linked `pylint` exe in my editor config is the one from the *base* environment.

I then launch my editor from a terminal with the correct conda environment (I use *vim* so launching the editor from a terminal is not a problem :) )